# How to access Link table (2 associations, 2 primary foreign key) In Entity Framework 4 database generated edmx file

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have 2 tables:

> User (UserID, UserName)
>
> Books (BookID, BookName)

Each user can hold many books, each book can be hold by many users.

so there is a link table:

> UserBook (PFK UserID, PFK BookID).

I've generated a Model using EF4, and I can see the association in the Model, 
but I can't see User.UserBook, nor Book.UserBook.
and no UserBook object as well.

how can I query this table ? add items ? etc... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User has Books collection, Books has User Collection, Missed that.
Idea came through :

[this article](http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/many-to-many-relationships-in-the-entity-data-model/)

Comment: Yep, EF doesn't need to map the join table if it contains only the FK's. It's smart enough to do an implicit join behind the scenes.